# Function to check equality between trees

Tags: tree, scheme, equality

How can I implement an equality function in Scheme that takes 2 trees and checks if they have both the same elements and structure?

Comment: Let's think about this a little. If we have two trees, each with one element, how could we tell if they were equal?

Comment: equality of lenght (since they are represented by lists), or with "eq?" maybe?

Comment: You're still trying to jump straight to a solution for the whole thing. That's not the correct way to go about it - you want to solve the smallest problem possible, and then build up a bigger solution out of that. So, if we have a tree of *one element* (it just contains the root node), and we have another tree of *one element*, how would we check if they were the same?

Comment: related: [tree-equal? in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390307/tree-equal-in-scheme).  That question has a specific programming error, but the accepted answer (disclaimer: it's mine) does include an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

recursion from the root each of the trees
if the root values are similar - continue with the left subtree, then right subtree
any difference - break

Answer (score 1):

We could use **equal?**

```
 (equal? '(a (b (c))) '(a (b (c))))
```

But, for some fun, following on from Vassermans mention of a "break", this might be a good chance to take advantage of Schemes continuation controlling power!

We can use **call/cc** to issue an early return if we notice any difference in the trees. This way we can just jump back to the callers continuation without having to unwind the stack.

Here is a really simple example. It assumes the trees are well-formed and only contain symbols as leaves, but it should hopefully demonstrate the concept. You'll see that the procedure explicitly accepts the continuation as a parameter.

```
 (define (same? a b return)
   (cond
     ((and (symbol? a) (symbol? b))      ; Both Symbols. Make sure they are the same.
       (if (not (eq? a b))
         (return #f)))
     ((and (empty? a) (empty? b)))       ; Both are empty, so far so good.
     ((not (eq? (empty? a) (empty? b)))  ; One tree is empty, must be different!
       (return #f))
     (else
       (begin
         (same? (car a) (car b) return)  ; Lets keep on looking.
         (same? (cdr a) (cdr b) return)))))
```

**call/cc** lets us capture the current continuation. Here is how I called this procedure:

```
 (call/cc (lambda (k) (same? '(a (b)) '(a (b)) k)))                      ; --> #t
 (call/cc (lambda (k) (same? '(a (b (c) (d e))) '(a (b (c) (d e))) k)))  ; --> #t
 (call/cc (lambda (k) (same? '(a (b (F) (d e))) '(a (b (c) (d e))) k)))  ; --> #f
 (call/cc (lambda (k) (same? '(a (b)) '(a (b (c) (d))) k)))              ; --> #f
```

Comment: What has `call/cc` got to do with the original question? It seems like you just wanted to use CPS here for no reason; it doesn't change the actual code that much. That said, you never `(return #t)` so `#t` should never be returned.

Comment: Yep, it was gratuitous. Is that bad form?

You are wrong about having to explicitly invoke the continuation. Try it...

Comment: I'm attempting to run it, but dr-scheme complains of missing else clauses on the ifs.  And #t has to show up at some point, does it not?  I'm going to try my hand at a continuation based search too.

Comment: Hey Tyr, that's odd, I am also using dr-Scheme (without any problems). If you want, just add #t in the else position.

The "trick" is that (and (empty? a) (empty? b)) in the cond form will return true implicitly.

Comment: It will also fail when given strings, maps, arrays or other things.  I would leave #t in the cond, especially since this is to intended to teach.  Good though.

Answer (score 0):

I've also got a continuation-ful answer.  But now I have two continuations, one if it is true, and one if it is false.  This is useful if you want to branch on the result.  I've also included 'same?, which hides all the continuations so you don't have to deal with them.

```
(define (same? a b)
  (call/cc (λ (k) (cont-same? a b (λ () (k #t)) (λ () (k #f))))))

(define (cont-same? a b return-t return-f)
  (define (atest c d)  
    ;; Are they foo?  If they both are, then true
    ;; If they both aren't false
    ;; if they are different, then we are done
    (if (and c d)
        #t
        (if (or c d)
            (return-f)
            #f)))

  (if (atest (null? a) (null? b))  ;; Are they both null, or both not null.
      (return-t)
      (if (atest (pair? a) (pair? b))
          (cont-same? (car a)
                      (car b) 
                      (λ () (cont-same? (cdr a) (cdr b) ;; If the head are the same, compare the tails
                                        return-t return-f)) ;; and if the tails are the same, then the entire thing is the same
                      return-f)          
          (if (equal? a b) ;; Both are atoms
              (return-t)
              (return-f)))))
```

Comment: @pantenlis You should check an answer as correct then, so that the question is closed.